# How to log user out of one phone when they sign in another - Kotlin Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am developing a fitness app and basically I would like to sign a user out of their application when they sign in to another device to prevent data from being ruined. (I am keeping all information in a .txt file until they hit "Save" and then it'll upload to Cloud Firestore.)

Upon being activated, I will call this to log the user out:
`this.mAuth?.signOut()`

However, I can't think of a way to do it quickly. Should I just use a Realtime database listener? When the user logs in, download a random string to their device and then to the database. Have the listener see if they match, if they don't log them out (because a new login reset the random string). Would this work or is there a better, more efficient way to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: What does *data from being ruined* mean? How will the data get ruined? *keeping all information in a .txt file until they hit "Save" and then it'll upload to Cloud Firestore*... why? What not just store it in Firestore in the first place? Perhaps the use case calls for something different but going this route defeats the purpose of a real time, online database.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have a real hard time with this is you use Firebase Auth sign-in status to try to gate control to their data.  There are going to be significant problems here, not the least of which that there is no guarantee that the user will actually sign out of one of their devices where they prviously signed in.  What if the device is lost?  What if the app is uninstalled?  You won't be able to detect these situations, and your database will forever show that the user is still signed in.

It would be far better to let the user decide for themselves if they want to continue where they left off on a different device, or simply abandon whatever they were doing before.  The user should have control.

If you need to detect which device they are using, generating a random string (a [UUID](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID)) and storing it locally would be sufficient.  However, you should know that local storage can be wiped out by the user if they simply choose to do so, or uninstall the app.  So you should be prepared for the UUID to suddenly become inactive without notice.

It's not clear from your question what the actual requirements are here, but I'm strongly suggesting that using auth sign-in state is not a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the user from logging in another application by doing the following:

Add a field `loggedIn : false`, if user logs in then update the field to become equal to `true`.

If the same user clicks on login button on another device, then check the value of `loggedIn`. If `loggedIn` is equal to `true`, show an alert (ex: you already have an active session) to prevent the user from logging in.